# What statistical method is most appropriate?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I am testing the differences between men and women pertaining to the perceived origin of criminal behavior. I distributed a survey with multiple choice options to pick what each individual thought the origin of crime was for the person described in the scenario. How would I test the differences between men and women pertaining to their answers in the multiple choice section?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing would be to use chi-square test for table where you cross-tabulate answers and sex. Null hypothesis would be that there is no association between distribution of answers and respondents sex.

Comment: Link: http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/chisq.htm

Comment: Thank you! So I would input the male and female responses for each scenario (I have six) seperately in SPSS (a stats program) right ?